# Lookup field returning multiple values

Tags: lookup-field

I need to create a lookup field that will allow me to pick multiple contacts, instead of just one. Is this possible? SF newbie here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not possible. If you need to assign multiple contacts you will have to create a related child object instead of a field.

Create an Object that lookups to the contact. This object will also have a parent lookup field to the object you want this multiple contacts against.

This is also called Juntion Object. Junction object is common data model schema used in Salesforce to create a [Many-many relationship](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.relationships_manytomany.htm&type=5) and seems like that is what you want in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. Will look into it.